# user table not created on django deployment but superuser created on heroku bash

Tags: django, bash, heroku

I'm trying to upload my first django app and I've been struggle with this issue for sometime, help is appreciated.

I already set up my project to be on heroku, I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DI_7Zja8Zc in which **django_heroku module** is used to configure DB, here is the link to library https://pypi.org/project/django-heroku/

The app throws the error on login as if user tables didn't exist but I already create a super user using the heroku bash feature, after apply migrations using "heroku run python manage.py migrate". When I run "ls" command on heroku bash this is my directory:

manage.py  Procfile  requirements.txt  runtime.txt  smoke  staticfile

"smoke" is my folder app, should I could see the db in this directory? if the db was not created how could I create a superuser using heroku bash feature?

This is the DB configuration that django gives me on server:

```
{'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
             'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
             'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
             'HOST': '',
             'NAME': PosixPath('/app/db.sqlite3'),
             'OPTIONS': {},
             'PASSWORD': '********************',
             'PORT': '',
             'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
                      'COLLATION': None,
                      'MIGRATE': True,
                      'MIRROR': None,
                      'NAME': None},
             'TIME_ZONE': None,
             'USER': ''}}
```

I see that db is sqlite3 and should be postgreSQL but I understand that django-heroku library should do that.

I don't know what other information could be useful because I have no experience deploying nothing so I will be pending on more information request to edit this question.

My gitignore file is this:

```
# Byte-compiled / optimized / DLL files
__pycache__/
*.py[cod]
*$py.class

# C extensions
*.so

# Distribution / packaging
.Python
build/
develop-eggs/
dist/
downloads/
eggs/
.eggs/
lib/
lib64/
parts/
sdist/
var/
wheels/
share/python-wheels/
*.egg-info/
.installed.cfg
*.egg
MANIFEST

*.manifest
*.spec

# Installer logs
pip-log.txt
pip-delete-this-directory.txt

# Unit test / coverage reports
htmlcov/
.tox/
.nox/
.coverage
.coverage.*
.cache
nosetests.xml
coverage.xml
*.cover
*.py,cover
.hypothesis/
.pytest_cache/
cover/

# Translations
*.mo
*.pot

# Django stuff:
*.log
local_settings.py
db.sqlite3
db.sqlite3-journal

# Flask stuff:
instance/
.webassets-cache

# Scrapy stuff:
.scrapy

# Sphinx documentation
docs/_build/

# PyBuilder
.pybuilder/
target/

# Jupyter Notebook
.ipynb_checkpoints

# IPython
profile_default/
ipython_config.py

# pyenv
#   For a library or package, you might want to ignore these files since the code is
#   intended to run in multiple environments; otherwise, check them in:
# .python-version

# pipenv
#   According to pypa/pipenv#598, it is recommended to include Pipfile.lock in version control.
#   However, in case of collaboration, if having platform-specific dependencies or dependencies
#   having no cross-platform support, pipenv may install dependencies that don't work, or not
#   install all needed dependencies.
#Pipfile.lock

# poetry
#   Similar to Pipfile.lock, it is generally recommended to include poetry.lock in version control.
#   This is especially recommended for binary packages to ensure reproducibility, and is more
#   commonly ignored for libraries.
#   https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/#commit-your-poetrylock-file-to-version-control
#poetry.lock

# PEP 582; used by e.g. github.com/David-OConnor/pyflow
__pypackages__/

# Celery stuff
celerybeat-schedule
celerybeat.pid

# SageMath parsed files
*.sage.py

# Environments
.env
.venv
env/
venv/
ENV/
env.bak/
venv.bak/

# Spyder project settings
.spyderproject
.spyproject

# Rope project settings
.ropeproject

# mkdocs documentation
/site

# mypy
.mypy_cache/
.dmypy.json
dmypy.json

# Pyre type checker
.pyre/

# pytype static type analyzer
.pytype/

# Cython debug symbols
cython_debug/
```

This is the bottom of my settings.py file:

...

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfile')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Thank you.

Comment: I have added a proper answer. Glad this worked for you. Unfortunately, there isn't a general way to be aware of this kind of thing. In this case, going to the source repository and noticing that it has been archived is a good hint that it has been abandoned. From there, [a web search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=heroku-django+abandoned) turns up the new library. But sometimes it's not so simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the `django-heroku` repository on GitHub](https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku) I think you'll find that it has been abandoned. It has a banner saying

> This repository has been archived by the owner. It is now read-only.

and has not had a new commit on the `master` branch since October, 2018.

[The `heroku-on-django` library](https://pypi.org/project/django-on-heroku/) aims to be an updated replacement for `django-heroku`:

> This has been forked from [django-heroku](https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku) because it was abandoned and then renamed to **django-on-heroku** because old project has been archived.

It is also somewhat stagnant (the most recent commit to `master` at the time of writing is from October, 2020) but it should work better than `django-heroku`.

In either case, make sure to put this at the bottom of your `settings.py` as indicated in the documentation:

```py
# Configure Django App for Heroku.
import django_on_heroku
django_on_heroku.settings(locals())
```